Ambiguous proof of the faster method to find minimal polynomial of an operator
I've come across a method to find minimal polynomial of an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ in Linear algebra done right. It starts with the fact we have to find smallest integer $m$ and coefficients $c_0, c_1, ..., c_m$ such that
$$c_0I + c_1T + ... + c_{m - 1}T^{m - 1} = -T^{m}$$
This comes straight from the definition of a minimal polynomial. If we write $T$ as its representation, which is a $dimV \times dimV$ matrix, then we obviously have $(dimV)^{2}$ equations(since we have to equate each entry of the matrix) and $m$ variables. Since $m \leq dimV$, the brute-force approach is to try each of them. This is easy to grasp.
But then, a faster method is proposed. Take any $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$. Let us plug this in
$$c_0v + c_1Tv + ... + c_{dimV - 1}T^{dimV - 1}v = -T^{dimV}v$$
where we have assumed $m = dimV$. Then, by using some basis $v_1, ..., v_{dimV}$ of $V$ for each $T^{k}v$, each side becomes a linear combination of $v_1, ..., v_{dimV}$. Due to its linear independence, we have to solve for $dimV$ equations with $dimV$ variables. The thing is the author claim that the unique coefficients $c_0, ..., c_{dimV - 1}$ must be the coefficients for the minimal polynomial !?
How is this so? Yes, they are the unique coefficients of the case $m = dimV$. But there's still smaller $m$, right? This theorem is somehow related.

And here's the illustrated example:


Because the polynomial given by these coeff divides the minimal polynomial and has same degree recall that every ideal of $k[x]$ is principal

You are misreading the book. The solution $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{\dim V-1}$ in general is not unique. However, as stated on p.145, 4/e, “If this system of equations has a unique solution $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{\dim V-1}$ (as happens most of the time), then the scalars $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{\dim V-1},1$ are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $T$...”.

@user1551 That's exactly what I'm asking :D.

I tried to find a duplicate but I did not get sufficiently close answers so I’ll answer.
Consider the ideal:
$$\mathcal{I}_v = \{p \in k[X] \mid p(T)v = 0\}$$
It is principal and has thus an unique unitary generator (since $v\neq0$) which is $\Pi_T^v$: the minimial polynomial of $v$ which you have found to be
$$\Pi_T^v = X^{\dim V} + c_{\dim V -1} X^{\dim V -1} + \cdots + c_1 X + c_0.$$
Now since $\Pi_T$ the minimal polynomial of $T$ verifies $\Pi_T(T) v = 0v = 0$, we have $\Pi_T \in \mathcal{I}_v$ thus $\Pi_T^v \mid \Pi_T $.
But they have the same degree which is $\dim V$ and they are both unitary so $\Pi_T^v = \Pi_T$.
NB: this kind of stuff comes from the study of Krylov subspaces which are the
$$\mathcal{K}(v) = k[T](u) = \operatorname{span} \{T^k v , \, k \geq 0\}$$
And you can always find some $v$ that verifies $\dim \mathcal{K}(v) = m$

Thanks! But you seem to touch upon something out of scope. Can you somehow to try another approach that fits more with the text? In-question text: https://linear.axler.net/ -page 145

It is not necessarily true that they have the same degree...

@JoshuaTilley it is one of the hypothesis made in the original post. You can always find some suitable $v$. And in a practical way, a random vector does the job

This method does not necessarily find the minimal polynomial. For instance if $T=\textrm{diag}(1,2)$ and $v=(1,0)$ then $Tv-Iv=0$ but $T-I\ne 0$. However, this only happens for certain bad vectors $v$ (any eigenvectors, for instance), and if we chose a vector at random, this unfortunate situation is unlikely.

Can you explain what you mean by $Tv - Iv = 0$ but $T - I \neq 0$? How is it related here?

The book concludes the reverse. I have edited question to include the illustrated example.
